# MapView remains empty Android

Tags: android, dictionary

I have a mapView and want to show marker on this mapView. 
The problem is that the mapView  remains empty. 
In debug modus, one has different Google Maps SDK API Key, I know this.
I tried release and debug modus with the correct API keys and the mapView is still empty.

THis is my code:

```
public class NavToLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    TextView textViewlocation
    Bundle bundle;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    MapView mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_to_location);
        textViewlocation = findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);


mapFragment = findViewById(R.id.mapView3);
        mapFragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(NavToLocation.this);


        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        setTextAddress(message);




   }


    public void setTextAddress(String text) {
        textViewlocation.setText(text);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mapFragment.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in no internet connection on your device.

Comment: I do hsve Internet

Comment: I doubt that you "checked everything". You have at least one syntax error at TextView textViewlocation - you missed the semicolon and its impossible that you do not have compilation errors. Besides what version of Android SDK API level do you use?

Comment: No I can compile. I have edited the source code before I pasted it here. There are some more array and string inits that I removed so that the code you currently see is much more overseeable and clear. I checked the release api key and it's correct.

Comment: I use Android sdk 29

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have used correct Map API_KEY with correct `package name` and `SHA1` (I think you missed it) value.
Also check whether you restrict the API_KEY for all request or not and also enable Google Map v2.

Comment: I checked everything